# angular 5 validation with template reference sync problems

Tags: angular, validation

I have a Form in a component 'reports-view.component.html' with few input controls (with labels).
the form  header is:

```
<form #gform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" autocomplete='off'>
```

then on each INPUT tag that I want to validate I use (date control for example !!) :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="startDate">
    {{'Reports-view.start' | translate }}
  </label>

  <input #datestart="ngModel" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="startDate" name="datestart" 
    [value]="startDate" required ngModel (input)='changeStartDate($event.target.value)' />

  <div *ngIf="datestart.invalid && (datestart.dirty || datestart.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    error
  </div>
</div>
```

The Datetime-Local control is initiated with the Current Time : `[value]="startDate"`

Now, on the bottom of the form I have :

```
<div class="form-actions col-ms-12">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-white" [disabled]="!gform.valid">
    {{'Reports-view.report' | translate }}
  </button>
</div>
<div class="form-actions col-ms-12">
  <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-success text-white" (click)='goBack()'>
    {{'Reports-view.cancel' | translate }}
  </button>
</div>
```

As seen the submit button is disabled and enabled according to the form validation : `[disabled]="!gform.valid"`

The SCSS is:

```
input:invalid {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

input:valid {
    border: 2px solid #b1a9a9;
}
```

The problems are :

1. when initializing the page , input of type datetime-local when initializing with a date (like 
   current) the INPUT border is NOT RED but the form is invalid so the submit button is disabled !!!, 
   until i change the date or time !!!!
2. when initializing the page, I have an EMPTY INPUT of type text ( the border is RED ). This input is 
   fed by another selection box . after the selection of something the EMPTY INPUT ( above ) is filled 
   the RED border disappears but the form is still invalid so the submit button is disabled until I'm 
   deleting or adding a character to the what was the 'EMPTY INPUT box' (now with the selected text).

Another phenomena is that when the page is initialized with empty input elements the borders are colored with RED but the div's with the error messages are not displayed !!!

Comment: You have not given the filed name to ngModel, you have to defined ngModel like this    [(ngModel)]="datestart", and you can assign the default value in *.component.ts file.. Ref: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: Thank you very much Govind Sah !!!! now it is working !!!